# How to fetch all PDAs owned by a program

Tags: pda, program

Is there a way to fetch all PDA's owned by a Solana program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solana cookbook has a great article about this RPC call that solves your problem. Bear in mind that this is an expensive request for the RPC nodes to fulfill, so please be gentle!

https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html#facts

Comment: Is there a way to get this data via CLI?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could always roll your own.

Answer (score 4):

adding to @HelmetFace answer, there are several constraints to keep in mind while using getProgramAccounts

1. not paginated, so calls to programs with huge number of accounts might not complete, and can return truncated results. use filters where applicable....
2. and filtering is a bit primitive ( uses memcmp to do byte wise comparison ) and not very expressive.